# Galois Theory books (in association with Abstract Algebra books)

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation

I know that there have been written similar posts, and I used them as a source for my question.

I ' m looking for a book for **Galois Theory** *(Construction of fields. Algebraic extensions - Classical Greek problems: constructions with ruler and compass. Galois extensions - Applications: solvability of algebraic equations - The fundamental theorem of Algebra - Roots of unity - Finite fields)*, which has the following characteristics:

- Logical order in the presentation of the theorems, definitions and generally of all concepts.
- Thorough analysis of each proof, example etc.
- Many examples and good exercises to solve.
- Also, to be suitable for self-study and for the first touch in the subject.

I should notice that I don't like Stewart's and Rotman's book.

What's your opinion for 1) Galois Theory by Bakers, 2) Galois Theory by Roman, 3) Fields and Galois Theory by Howie, 4) Galois Theory by Jean-Pierre Escofier. And do you believe that it is better to read from a general Abstract Algebra book, such that Fraleigh's/ Dummit's and Foote's/Gallian's?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: While this is a specific question, the second part is obviously highly opinion-based. You should remove it.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It might be opinion based, however I think I will be helpful for many people.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend *Galois' Theory of Algebraic Equations*, by Jean-Pierre Tignol (2nd edition, World Scientific, 2016).

Comment: Tignol's book is especially notable for its historical information. (I haven't seen the 2nd edition, however.) For a lot of specific examples and calculations, see [**Classical Galois Theory, With Examples**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0821813757) by Lisl Gaal.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro I strongly agree with you.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I found Tignol's book great, but it's not what I was looking for. It's more historic and less an introduction to classical Galois Theory.

Comment: Other suggestions please?

Comment: Chris, you might want to look at the treatments in Fraleigh's [**A First Course in Abstract Algebra**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0201763907) and Herstein's [**Topics in Algebra**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0471010901). Fraleigh's treatment is especially elementary and excellent for self-study (I read much of the 1st edition of his book on my own), but it might be too limited in scope for your needs. Herstein's treatment is a little more advanced, but still very well written, which I can personally testify to, having taken a 2-semester algebra sequence using his text.

Comment: Also, you may want to look at Hadlock's [**Field Theory and Its Classical Problems**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/088385032X), and perhaps scan through the bibliography of [this manuscript](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/316692623_A_detailed_and_elementary_solution_to_x17_1) (also located [here](http://pballew.net/Constructable_17gon.pdf)). The items in this bibliography were not chosen for someone interested in Galois theory, but some of them might still be of use to you.

Comment: My friend, thank you for all these useful information. Any other comment or suggestion (at any time) is welcome!

Answer (score 2):

You clearly know which books are available on the subject. I would like to comment on your request. "Also, to be suitable for self-study and for the first touch in the subject."

The lecture notes of Christopher Cooper on Galois Theory ( Math338 ) are just that: suitable for self-study, and for a first touch in the subject.

https://coopersnotes.net/third_galois.html

Comment: Thank you for your post. These notes are very useful (and with answers in exercises)!

Comment: Link is broken and I can't find it anywhere on the internet.

Comment: @ThomasShelby I'll see if I can find my copy next Monday.

Answer (score 1):

I’ve learned Galois Theory from Siegfried Bosch’s Book *Algebra*. It’s German, though. To my knowledge, it has been translated to English, but I do not know how available English versions are.

Anyway, it pretty much fits the bill: It is very clean, leaves absolutely nothing out (not even set-theoretical considerations when discussion transcendence degree), it is well-structured and yet light-to-read. And it covers, of course, everything you have listed.

It also has additional (starred) sections on more advanced topics. I most of all value his introductions to each chapter which motivate the following material really well and give a good overview of what to expect (which makes it really suitable for self-study). The introductory chapter also gives some historical context.

Comment: Thank you for your post. This book looks pretty good but I have searched for it and I couldn't find it in an English version!